# Swift Inherited Protocols and Conformance Checking for the Parent-Protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I noticed that in Swift 2.2, if I have a `protocol A`, and then a `protocol B: A` which inherits from A, checking for conformance to the parent protocol like this fails: `if objectConformingToBWhichInheritsFromA is A` evaluates to `false`, as does the `as?` variant.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Thank you, it turned out that the problem lays elsewhere, so Im going to delete this post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asked question is not correct - there was a different problem which caused the person to ask this question

Answer (score 1):

My Playground tells a different story

```
protocol A { }
protocol B: A { }    
class Foo: B { }

let foo = Foo()

foo is A // true
foo is B // true
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your answer. Turns out that the problem was elsewhere, basically that I was blind and that in the project protocols are getting mixed up.